# Getting the path of a file - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, path, xslt-2.0, concatenation

I have the following tree file structure:

```
ROOT   (ID 0000)
 -  FILE 1 (ID 0001) 
 -  FILE 2 (ID 0002)
 -   - FILE 2.1 (ID 0003)
 -   - FILE 2.2 (ID 0004)
 -   -   -  FILE 2.2.1 (ID 0005) 
 -  FILE 3 (ID 0006)
```

All of them are XML files with the following structure:

```
<asset id="0002" name="FILE 2">
  <child_asset_rel child_asset="0003"/>
  <child_asset_rel child_asset="0004"/>
</asset>
```

So that, the element `<child_asset_rel>` just appears if the main element has children. Also we can see that in the XML we just can detect the 'direct children' of an asset, i.e. each file doesn't know if it has *grandchildren*, so we must look for children in each file.

The input is the XML of the root file. It is as follows:

```
<asset id="0000" name="ROOT">
   <child_asset_rel child_asset="0001"/>
   <child_asset_rel child_asset="0002"/>
   <child_asset_rel child_asset="0006"/>
</asset>
```

Also I have a function `get-asset('ID')` which returns the XML file of the asset with the ID that we pass as parameter.

Ex: get-asset(0002) will return the XML example above.

What I want is to get a list of asset names showing the full path as follows:

```
<file href="FILE 1"/>
<file href="FILE 2/FILE 2.1"/>
<file href="FILE 2/FILE 2.2/FILE 2.2.1"/>
<file href="FILE 3"/>
```

As you can see in the example above, the root element must not be included in the path.

I have tried a lot of solutions but I don't seem to be able to get the result I want. I tried to use a `for-each` in a recursive function but the result is not the expected one.

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use, can you show us the code of the function `get-asset`? Is that an extension function or an XSLT function? What is the input to the stylesheet, an asset id?

Comment: The version of the XSLT is 2.0, Sorry but I cannot show you the code of the `get-asset` function, due to license reason. The functions just receive an ID and returns the XML of the file with that ID.  The in put of the stylesheet is anothe XML which is a root of all the structure I mentioned above.  I edit the entry to clarify the input question.

Comment: Why does the input XML not contain `<child_asset_rel child_asset="0001"/>` although the structure given at the beginning of your question shows `FILE 1 (ID 0001) `.

Comment: Sorry I missed. Yes it includes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline of templates:

```
<xsl:template match="asset[@name = 'ROOT']" priority="5">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="child_asset_rel/get-asset(@child_asset)">
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="''"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="asset[child_asset_rel]">
  <xsl:param name="path" select="concat($path, @name, '/')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="child_asset_rel/get-asset(@child_asset)">
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$path"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="asset[not(child_asset_rel)]">
  <xsl:param name="path"/>
  <file href="{$path}{@name}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested as you did not provide sample data and sample code to test with, but should give you an idea.

Comment: I have change one line. The value of the second apply templates, it means: from `<xsl:with-param name="path" select="$path"/>` to `<xsl:with-param name="path" select="concat($path, @name, '/')"/>`